# How to create a pre .Net installer .msi file from .msm merge modules?

Tags: windows-installer, merge-module

I have some .msm merge modules (for Crystal Reports if you must know) that I want to convert to one single .msi installer package. I can do this with a Visual Studio setup project, but then I cannot avoid a requirement for .Net being included in the package.

- Is there a workaround in Visual Studio (2008/2010)?
- Are there any free third party utilities that can perform this task?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Perhaps for my reputation it is better to delete this question, but just in case there are more nutheads like me:

The Setup project creates two files: the setup.exe and the myapp.msi.
Setup.exe will install .Net whatever you do, but if you run the .msi and you are sure no dependecies on .Net exist, it will not demand a .Net framework installation...

I am now going to get drunk...